# Can I disable some parts (functions) of cocoa pod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm in need of using a certain cocoa pod, but it uses a couple of functions that are unwanted to say the least. Can I disable them without copying the whole library into my repo and changing it there?

Many thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disable"? Are they being executed and you want to stop it, or do you just not want them imported? And which pod is it?

Comment: If the pod has subpods, you can. Is that what you are looking for? Example: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage.podspec if you want or not MapKit also...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
from module import function1, function2
```

and so on to import the functions you want instead. Remember that the bit thats before most functions usually is removed now, but thats the way to import only what you need